# Is there a way to send EOF to the process reading a message queue?

Tags: c, unix, message-queue, sysv-ipc

I have one process sending data through a message queue with `msgsnd`.  Another process reading from the queue with `msgrcv`.  The reading process needs to wait until it has all messages before it can continue.  How can I tell it that all messages have been sent?

The way I've been doing it is after the sender has sent all its messages it then checks the number of messages in the queue in a while loop. When there are no more messages it closes the queue.

That tells the reading process to continue doing other things.  This doesn't seem very reliable though.  Many time the sending process will get stuck in an infinite loop of checking the queue status.

Is there a way for me to just send an EOF message and have the reading process watch for that?  Then I could just send EOF and have the sending process exit.

Comment: I'm having difficulty isolating the problem you are trying to solve.  Why does the sender care when the msgs are processed and done?  There is nothing stopping it from closing the queue and exiting after it is done writing.  The messages will still be there for the reader(s).  This is one of the benefits of msg queues.

Comment: I thought closing the queue blocked it?  Or at least gives the reader a value of -1 for msgcv

Comment: Not at all.  The queue is like a drop box.  You don't even need a reader & writer at the same time.  The queues are kernel persistant and the msgs will remain until something reads them, deletes the queue, or the OS is rebooted.

Comment: ah thanks!  I did a bit more reading on it.  This helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Normally the receiver notices that the sender has finished sending because it tries to receive the next message and the receive call indicates that there was nothing left to receive. With communication through file descriptors (pipes, sockets), closing the is how you “send EOF”, and the `read` call returns 0 bytes. With message queues, it's a little different, because they are message-based rather than streams and there are often multiple senders.

You can call [`msgctl`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/msgctl.html) with the command `IPC_RMID`. This causes any waiting or subsequent call to [`msgrcv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/msgrcv.html) (or [`msgsnd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/msgsnd.html)) to return `-EIDRM` (`-EINVAL` on some BSD systems). The problem with this approach is that there may be messages pending in the queue that the receiver has not read yet and will thus we lost.

Instead, when the sender has nothing else to, have it send a message onto the queue that says “I'm finished”. In the receiver, when you receive this message, remove the queue. This works well when you use the queue between threads of one process. If there are multiple processes, the sender could die without having send the termination message.

How to handle the multi-process case will depend on the structure of your application, and in particular what the reading process wants to do when the sender is dead. One way you can detect this is by having a pipe between the sender and the receiver. Have a thread on the receiver listen on that pipe; if it detects the end of the file, it can

1. set a variable that is shared with the thread that calls `msgrcv`;
2. peek at the queue (`msgctl` with `IPC_STAT`);
3. if the queue is empty (`msg_qnum == 0`), remove it.

Comment: I tried sending a final message that says there is no more data and have the reader watch for that.  I need to test it more but this seems to work so far.